# how can I remove the white are black screen which comes before splash screen?

Tags: flutter, screen, splash-screen

when I open the app, white screen appears with icon. Then only the splash screen appears.
I have already tried changing the background colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package.  You can read the [setting-the-splash-screen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#1-setting-the-splash-screen) section for details. You need to cover

```yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  # This package generates native code to customize Flutter's default white native splash screen
  # with background color and splash image.
  # Customize the parameters below, and run the following command in the terminal:
  # flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
  # To restore Flutter's default white splash screen, run the following command in the terminal:
  # flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove

  # color or background_image is the only required parameter.  Use color to set the background
  # of your splash screen to a solid color.  Use background_image to set the background of your
  # splash screen to a png image.  This is useful for gradients. The image will be stretch to the
  # size of the app. Only one parameter can be used, color and background_image cannot both be set.
  color: "#42a5f5" #here the color
```

Then follow  [run-the-package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#2-run-the-package)

```
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Comment: It's not an answer to this question. this indeed might work, but it's just a tweak or workaround to a real problem.

Comment: @szakes1  did you tested this approach?  this will override the config by running build runner. I will encourage you to check this package while this is flutter favorite

Answer (score -1):

Flutter splash screen is built on top iOS Storyboard and Android Activity. You need to edit these files to proceed.